# Show Only Fields Needed

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I’m trying to make an excel spread sheet that will provide only questions needed depending on the color they pick

Example: 
If they pick blue I would like a to show only the questions then need to fill out for blue and restrict access to any other colors.

There much be a better way to show only information you want depending on which color is chosen without having to put IF starts all over on the spread sheet

IF( A1, Blue, IF( show Blue Sheet Only, All Sheets, Blank ))

IF condition1 THEN
   show Blue Sheet Only
ELSEIF condition2 THEN
   All Sheets
ELSE
   Blank
END IF

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You could use a select case statement to evaluate the cell's colour, something like this should get you started:

```
Select Case Range("A1").Interior.Color
   Case vbBlue
     Sheets("Blue").Activate
   Case vbRed
     Sheets("Red").Activate
   Case vbGreen
     Sheets("Green").Activate
   Case Else
     MsgBox "Color not recognised"
End Select
```